# Calculating total price with quantity on new order

Tags: vue.js

I am new at vue js. I get a multidimensional array from server side and should render that array into html. The simple logic is that i get a meal data with his title and size and options. Each size of meal has a price. Also, there are additional extra options that belong to this meal. And each extra options have price too.

I can display a price when user choose a size of meal. It calls subtotal price. However if user will increase or decrease the quantity of meal, i cant figure out how to make a calculation like this: ( add_price * total)
When user also chooses an extra addition, it is calculated too. It calls Extra Amount. But if user again will increase a quantity of each options, the calculation will not worked correctly.

I prefer creating a new array with selected prices and quantities. That makes it more complicated. Probably, it is not a good approach, especially when I want to send all selected data to firebase ( prices, quantities, subtotal, total)

```
<div id="app">

  <div>
    <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
    <input type="number" value="1" :v-model="quantity" class="left">
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <div v-for="(optGroup, index) in item.opt_groups" class="opt-group" :key="index">
    <h4>{{ optGroup.title }}:</h4>
    <div class="form-row" v-for="(opt, key) in optGroup.opts" :key="key">
      <label v-bind:for="'opt[' + index + ']'">
        <input type="radio" :value="opt.add_price" v-model="price[index]">
        {{ opt.title }}
        <div v-if="index == 1">
          <input type="number"  min="1" value="1">
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="amount" v-if="price[index] > 0">$ {{ price[index] }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>Subtotal: {{ subTotal }}</p>
  <p>Extra: {{ extra }}</p>
  <p>Total: {{ total }}</p>



</div>

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {

    quantity: 1,
  price: [],
   item:
   {
     "title": "Green Salad",
     "opt_groups": [
       {
         "title": "Choose Size",
         "opts": [
           {
             "id": 4,
             "title": "Small",
             "add_price": 4.25
           },
           {
             "id": 5,
             "title": "Big",
             "add_price": 6
           }
         ]
       },
       {
         "title": "Extra cheese",
         "opts": [
           {
             "id": 10,
             "title": "Feta cheese (small)",
             "add_price": 3
           },
           {
             "id": 70,
             "title": "Feta cheese (Big)",
             "add_price": 5
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
  },
  computed: {
    subTotal(){
      return this.price[0] || 0
    },
    extra(){
      return this.price[1] || 0
    },
    total(){
      return this.price.reduce((total, value) => total + value, 0)
    }
  }
});
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hf8xtoqw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

on line 5, you ahve `:v-model="quantity"`

this should be just `v-model="quantity"`

removing that colon should help